# time variable doesn't works in server, but in local going well. PYTHON

Tags: python, server, localhost, auto-update

I'm using the datetime.datetime.now() variable to get the current date.
When I'm using it in local enviroment this works pretty good, but when I use it in Production enviroment (SERVER) this doesn't update to the next day.

---

code:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
year1 = str(today.year)

if len(str(today.day)) == 1:
    day1= "0" + str(today.day)
else:
    day1= str(today.day)


if len(str(today.month)) == 1:
    month1= "0"+ str(today.month)
else:
    month1= str(today.month)


GetDate1 = str(year1)+str(month1)+str(day1)

return(GetDate1)
```

---

{
today is 2019-08-06 **********************************

execute the code in localhost:
Returns 20190806

it's good

Execute the code in server
Returns 20190806

it's good
}

---

{
today is 2019-08-07 **********************************

execute the code in localhost:
Returns 20190807

it's good

Execute the code in server
Returns 20190806

**it's WRONG!!!!! doesn't update**
}

Comment: Same issue for me. I've read (don't remember where) that I should use `datetime.now` instead of `datetime.now()` (remove parenthesis). Because when the function is called once, it's like "cached" by **Apache** on production server and if you call the functon again, "cached" value is returned. For local dev, this behavior  is different with **Mamp** and date is well updated. But this tip didn't work for me. Still searching ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know is not a good practice, but this works for me:

**I created a JOB to reset the WSGI each day at midnite**

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
```

to this:

```
today = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

and both will show the same time.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanx

Comment: doesn't work, the problem maybe is the server is in United States and I'm in Colombia, and Im using GOOGLE COMPUTE ENGINE as my server manager

Comment: Well, utcnow should return UTC time, so it's irrelevant where you and your server are located. What are the outputs?

Comment: The output is the same date when I updated the code on the server, I even tried this:`hour1 = '000000' GetDate1 = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')+str(hour1)`